# How can I remove all anchor + anchor text from a Textaea?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, anchor

I'm getting something like this in a textarea:

```
`Some text <a href="">Click me!</a>`
```

how can I remove all chars included `Click me!` from `< to >` using `javascript` `replace` method or using something similar?

Comment: This question makes no sense...

Comment: @pagewil He's asking for a regular expression to strip out anchor tags along with the anchor text within the tags.  @jartuad what you need is a regular expression.  You can probably find an example with a quick google search.

Comment: @pagewil thanks anyway and I'm sorry for my english, but STO is not WWE (C).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var ta = document.getElementById('id-of-textarea');
ta.value = ta.value.replace(/<a(|\s[^>]*)>[\s\S]*?<\/a>/gi, '');
```

will cover the most likely cases. You probably [shouldn't generalize this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags) to a more complex situation though.

This does not replace the [need to sanitize your input](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_%28XSS%29) on the server side. In fact, the above should probably be done on the server side if at all possible, and a JavaScript approach (probably ignored by the spam bots anyways) used only if, say, this is off-the-shelf blogging software and you cannot modify it.

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Sorry for the delay, I had a serious problem with my Internet connection.

Comment: @jartaud: There was a slight mistake in the above regex which caused `text here` in `<a href="foo">hello</a>text here<a href="bar">world</a>` to be deleted. I changed `[\s\S]*` to `[\s\S]*?`, which fixes it.

Answer (score 1):

you can check this [google caja plugin](http://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/trunk/src/com/google/caja/plugin/html-sanitizer.js) to sanitize the input. BUT! you MUST sanitize your input on the server side too.

Comment: Almost, but not quite.  That sanitizer will only remove html markup.  What he wants to remove is the markup *and* the text within the anchor tags.